# How to download a zip file using the command line

Tags: zip, dropbox, wget, curl

I would like to download a heavy compressed zip file from either dropbox or the UCF-Crime video dataset. The [dataset's website](https://www.crcv.ucf.edu/projects/real-world/) points out these two links to get the dataset from :

- https://www.dropbox.com/sh/75v5ehq4cdg5g5g/AABvnJSwZI7zXb8_myBA0CLHa?dl=0
- https://visionlab.uncc.edu/download/summary/60-data/477-ucf-anomaly-detection-dataset

Each time I try to download the dataset through wget or curl I fail. I know I'm trying the wrong way. My examples take as parameter the visionlab url.

```
wget https://visionlab.uncc.edu/download/summary/60-data/477-ucf-anomaly-detection-dataset/UCF-Anomaly-Detection-Dataset.zip
```

or

```
curl https://visionlab.uncc.edu/download/summary/60-data/477-ucf-anomaly-detection-dataset/UCF-Anomaly-Detection-Dataset.zip
```

At each trial, I face this error message :

```
ERROR: cannot verify visionlab.uncc.edu's certificate, issued by ...
Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to visionlab.uncc.edu insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

EDIT:
I tried to download the dataset by enabling the `--no-check-certificate` option. However, I am getting the following message :

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://visionlab.uncc.edu/download/summary/60-data/477-ucf-anomaly-detection-dataset/UCF-Anomaly-Detection-Dataset.zip
--2020-12-10 13:58:23--  https://visionlab.uncc.edu/download/summary/60-data/477-ucf-anomaly-detection-dataset/UCF-Anomaly-Detection-Dataset.zip
Resolving visionlab.uncc.edu (visionlab.uncc.edu)... 
WARNING: cannot verify visionlab.uncc.edu's certificate, issued by ...:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-12-10 13:58:24 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: So, perhaps you should try the "--no-check-certificate" ?

Comment: Is it secure to use "--no-check-certificate" ? I downloaded the dataset safely on my computer after clicking on the button. However, I would like to download the same dataset through the command line on a remote server.

Comment: So have you used *--no-check-certificate* as directed?  What safety concerns specifically are you concerned about? The download probably isn’t even suppose to be https since there is absolutely no reason for it to be transferred over a secured http connection

Comment: As I would like to download the dataset on a server I don't own but where I possess a session, I'm afraid to provoke security issues to the server if I use the "--no-check-certificate" option.

Comment: On a server that you don't own, there may very well be a firewall that could act as a "person in the middle", which would leave you no other option but to "--no-check-certificate".

Comment: I've just tried to use the option "-no-check-certificate" to download the dataset on my own computer, but it seems that the file name added to the webpage link doesn't help to locate the file correctly

Comment: That is a completely diferent problem, isn't it?  "Obtaining the correct URL", eg.

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a straightforward solution to my problem, but I implemented a workaround that can work on the dropbox links.
With the help of a friend I could extract these downloading links for each dropbox file.

I put these url links within a text file `UCF-Crime_download_links.txt`

```
Anomaly_Train.txt,https://ucfd47a3132502df8b7da1078048.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFD94aIgIcZePmQnMUR9GXKvwiKLuWkTXQlJUbrCIcuOtEbnrhq0WYHD3_tE6VNIutXB-0uuD4KSnGT_XbbcYKRGo33iS5p2_MNLZ0cMGqAttw/file?_download_id=097716663047956452461729849578513492367789635489118937591573887371&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
Anomaly-Videos-Part-1.zip,https://ucd2b23b12c729fc4c377d2a4559.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFDZ8seM8pKTbOBVnx8XejXk_oJHQXEQsSoGomJSLcmrwaToJjaDPhGe4i7WDKQdzVKcRbd3LhpTFXfaKq-HLvM77kg10eGbzj39azmYeecEYQ/file?_download_id=0363965750577266464342348679706188869134262358521904742084241846&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
Anomaly-Videos-Part-2.zip,https://uc2bed7c7a17a15220b13be4a2e6.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFBSk-HeNvTfjVihchn8wJ4ZARgFpfsvx0xI_wPyfnByA0Jont0INM_M8FEzSUUzOYRKA1WLJ1CY5cFHZD4KJasNIhQWPCEY33OL1WR40lmd3g/file?_download_id=0579378818307589862973462645032838382079214641391144587467813138293&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
Anomaly-Videos-Part-3.zip,https://uc92f1b103a1be39f95efe1c6144.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFCfynAnLeJI_qWCDNlqunMW5MOov14OQnZRHuexd-GZJrstjFdpu5BAf8IUxGMOUWJNz1FPDni-fE1YABI13LOXLQoQYmli-kRHrOaF1ImjYg/file?_download_id=727024674397661849253116806809373576342610272509334976130541060124&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
Anomaly-Videos-Part-4.zip,https://uc0c9ade9be14edadc6215823861.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFDjzs0TcEM_xsCnb6X_43Q4Nzhr4yB5ccPcKusL9TGDgeCVVuahZ0rT5S_0PiMDRh5HvzkJ3INGEXKrednLF-ZFtKxDHSDyktHOheNo6Cr4JQ/file?_download_id=55589026333033841043625854492820157750952578262247539791205866326&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
Normal_Videos_for_Event_Recognition.zip,https://uc0c2c5bfde8f04a8f545a0f7c48.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFDzshYfN81gu1bweDMKjubBmNuyVNGI4srsoXyFXB3yNYN39mi5MZWiCYk9RQ97-ntZLzV97zNefXDs3N-16rb4IYH0eZHLvR2F15ePudQjGw/file?_download_id=754017652375024472883071931908466187771437616567601330606754946&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
ReadMe-Anomaly-Detection.txt,https://uc2ae171f6610223bc44b0571a06.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFAExBD5DyYH3mIUFFwlh0AXQJ1zNBhlria77CyD5EKAr29aJTLYOV0-67iPv993peIgTl6bmV1TLcYVjypvLlABdlr_supYpWNlaJif71H1xw/file?_download_id=987765206572950519523413130201916364276953226782661290955905419846&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
Temporal_Anomaly_Annotation_for_Testing_Videos.txt,https://uc1b4ac9977c9671dcd4d9e7769f.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFAUo61sFDlmJO2jH1k-lg9PkyuMgB-ra363o6l5zS7d5UmCn7zdDB224a86DfNX-oqQk1gdefwZFMHOK2_wvJP2FvJuL8Ft_eFYdvh7Ez9JrA/file?_download_id=51676525513664041950873962382331226008355206984435667655330876461&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
Testing_Normal_Videos.zip,https://uc4726690c34a81dd2daf9b07b6e.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFDkHyWEpPY-ujMPqFW1jCt6-1N0tFH0dkHE13Zx-DMbM-9OyVbsAVaxAQX322yYGRWGelhHBLYVjOEYa8VJiI_Bx3eiwzKPjQAEWjT5OFbhAg/file?_download_id=570733229890446284890063923590291221261415804728635013945386341994&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
Training-Normal-Videos-Part-1.zip,https://ucc4a7ebb4b9f43444740e1bf130.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFAXVtO9deicS-czConfc8qyFh7EY4Mdw97L35u8jB-fUXDMFCC0fJGrh2cUw_daJ44eR4wEIkmm9ADPC5thIZ2aOyJTXTuiJ8O_72F-dqZVjA/file?_download_id=48412181900856838492867675657194829029734593236333792964919684665&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
Training-Normal-Videos-Part-2.zip,https://uc924337e0d8e7a24323eb0e7174.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFAw_Eym3ICikx0fA_-PSyihqzNXQqJfVVfzCanJa0aoVIF84U644oKm2Kd7ZuUrUwSlfRxrCTsr8Sb1pGLKb485GaKnBCV49NYuyssjT4xSRw/file?_download_id=655411935603899202237191315622855477671008665861545359350399844076&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
UCF_Crimes-Train-Test-Split.zip,https://uc2807770edb067ebc8f6751f4d0.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BFAxnOoeRrGLmch7uOB6U_W7bVF00uUsAuHU-MZmNUz7CXMjXZuCk-TOUMyzus23bC83gltkAeMaiW7rQ7pS7gOl-Rf8zN6dvrx7yFDrGkt1LA/file?_download_id=221324488118949561849144925330559290896952119513818184423550876863&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1
```

You get these links by attempting to download each file following these steps:

[image]

[image]

And then I implemented this python code `download_ucf-crime.py` to download each of them:

```
import os

filepath = "UCF-Crime_download_links.txt"
file = open(filepath,"r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line_parts = line.split(',')
    link_filename = line_parts[0]
    link_url = line_parts[1]
    os.system('wget -O %s %s'%(link_filename,link_url))
file.close()
```

My friend suggested me to check the dropbox API for a cleaner solution: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python

Answer (score 2):

When you visit [the dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/75v5ehq4cdg5g5g/AABvnJSwZI7zXb8_myBA0CLHa?dl=0), you'll find links that can be used by wget.  I've tried the first:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/sh/75v5ehq4cdg5g5g/AABvnJSwZI7zXb8_myBA0CLHa?dl=0
```

Also, you may need to update your local certificates:

```
update-ca-certificates -f
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. When I click on each file, I get its download link. However is there a faster way to get all the downloadable file links from this dropbox page to download them : a sort of "ls" command of this dropbox page directory.

Comment: I'd try the wget recursive option.

Comment: I did a retry by using the recursive option "wget -r ..." and even by setting ?dl to 1 : "?dl=1", it doesn't work.

Comment: Changing a number somewhere in an URL will rarely give you a working URL.  I meant doing a recursive get from the dropbox page containing all  the downloads.  But I've tried it and it fails.  Now there are 10 zips on that page. Why not copy those links and put the wgets in a script?